# c++ node list - NULL test not working

Tags: c++

I wanted to test the following code (which works fine for a non-null list) to see what would happen in the case of an empty list (in which case the head would be null).

hence the code which applies to filling the list is commented out..

But for some strange reason, the test for NULL in print_nodes() just doesnt seem to work. ive added some debug cout calls to see (and also checked using gdb) but whilst the value does indeed appear to be NULL, any if statements dont seem to test the equivalence properly..

any idea why?

many thanks!

```
   #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
  char dat;
  node *nextPtr;
};

//inserts new node and returns pointer
node* new_node(char data, node* prevNode);

//adds a new node at the head ofthe list
void new_head (node *head_, char dat_);

//inserts new node after *before
void insert_node (node *before, char dat_);

//runs through and prints the list - requires first node (head)
void print_nodes (node *head);


int main() {
  cout <<endl << endl;
  cout << endl << "*******************RUN******************" <<endl <<endl;

  node* head = NULL;

  if (head == NULL) { 
    cout << "head null"; //this works here
  }


  //head non-standard
  //  node* head = new node;
  //  head->dat ='a';

  /*
  node* b = new_node('b', head);
  node* c = new_node('c', b);
  node* d = new_node('d', c);
  node* e = new_node('e', d);
  node* f = new_node('f', e);

  */
  print_nodes(head);

  insert_node(head,'N');

  print_nodes(head);

  cout << endl << "*******************END RUN******************" <<endl;
  return 0;
}

node* new_node(char data, node* prevNode) {
  node* tempPtr = new node;
  tempPtr->dat = data;
  tempPtr->nextPtr = NULL; //standard
  prevNode->nextPtr = tempPtr;
  return tempPtr;
}

void new_head (node *head_, char dat_) {

}

void insert_node (node *before, char dat_) {
  node* tempPtr = new node;
  tempPtr->dat = dat_;

  tempPtr->nextPtr = before->nextPtr;
  before->nextPtr = tempPtr;

}


void print_nodes (node *head) {

  node* tempPtr = head;

  cout << "\nPrinting nodes..." <<endl;

  if (tempPtr == NULL) { //this test is not working.. why?
    cout << "tempPtr is NULL";
    return; 
  } else { //only run in the non null case
    for (tempPtr; tempPtr != NULL; tempPtr = tempPtr->nextPtr) {
      cout << "Current node content: " << tempPtr->dat <<endl;
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem: head was not allocated, but insert accesses its "next element":

```
before->nextPtr = tempPtr;
```

`head` is passed in as `before`, and you didn't allocate memory for `head`. Hence you dereference a NULL pointer here.

Could it be that your application crashes as a result, and the printout to `cout` isn't done because `cout` is buffered?

Try to:

1. Remove the call to `insert`
2. Change `cout` to `cerr` (unbuffered)

Report the results of these changes.

Comment: genius! that was it! whilst it was showing me the segmention fault right after accessing the print function - it was the insert function after all - thanks for the tip on the cerr, will use that in the future instead.

many thanks!

Comment: "genius" in these cases arrives after a few times of banging one's head against the desk on similar occasions :-)

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me using g++ 4.4.1 on windows. The message is displayed and then it crashes, because of other issues in the code. You are probably not seeing the message because the crash occurs before the output buffer containing the message is flushed.

In general, it is a good idea to write diagnostic messages to standard error (cerr) rather than standard output, as the error stream is not buffered.

Answer (score 0):

allocate head before insertion :

```
node * head = new node;
memset(head, 0, sizeof(node));
```